# Compile: Which class is called?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there any way to determine which code / which class is executed clicking "Compile" in AOT?
I'd like to implement some tests before executing compilation!

Comment: My guess is it's the XppCompiler class: \System Documentation\Classes\XppCompiler. This is a kernel class so you can't change it. Are you triggering the compile yourself? Why not extend the BP framework (SysBPCheck class) and create a best practice?

Comment: @KlaasDeforche I'd like to reject compiling an object if it is checked-out by another user. I've already written a query which determines if an object is checked out, but if I trigger compile on a checked-out object, the user who checked out the object won't be able to commit / check-in the object, because "object on the server is newer". So I'd like to prevent objects checked-out from being compiled by another person. Adding sth in SysCPCheck would be too late in this process.